# Error bars missing from list plot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make a `ListPlot` with errorbars by using `Filling`. However, is some cases, some of the errorbars are missing. Why? Here is an example:

```
test = 
  {{{12.5, 2.3458330528920013}, {8., 2.026674892670841}, {13.9, 2.414291671785107}, 
    {11.9, 2.914023786219254}, {11.5, 2.722805195984148}, {7.9, 2.0961107498634486}}, 
   {{12.5, 2.1850350078313467}, {8., 1.9120983867236054}, {13.9, 2.242970208104576}, 
    {11.9, 2.724036258443863}, {11.5, 2.6537600418574083}, {7.9, 2.020026681009219}}, 
   {{12.5, 2.265434030361674}, {8., 1.9693866396972233}, {13.9, 2.3286309399448415}, 
    {11.9, 2.8190300223315585}, {11.5, 2.6882826189207782}, {7.9, 2.0580687154363337}}};

ListPlot[test, PlotRange -> {{5, 15}, All}, PlotMarkers -> {"up", "down", "center"}, 
  Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]]}}]
```

[image]

Your help is appreciated.
thanks, L

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it works if you sort the sublists to be in increasing order,

```
ListPlot[Sort /@ test, PlotRange -> {{5, 15}, All}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {"up", "down", "center"}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]]}}]
```

[image]